# Regex for IPaddress/prefix

Tags: java, regex, ip-address

I have a regex for IP address validation, but I need a regex for prefix validation, where the expected form is "IP Address/Prefix".

The conditions are:

1. The prefix value should not be greater than 128
2. The prefix value should be divisible by 4.

Could anyone please help me to create a regex for prefix validation?

Comment: Could you please post an example ipaddress and what the prefix value looks like?

Comment: All numbers are divisible by 4. Do you mean "evenly divisible"?

Comment: Marc B: From number theory, the term "divisible" always means "evenly divisible".

Comment: regexp is the wrong tool for this job. Do you _really_ need a regexp solution, or are you just guessing that you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do calculations using regex (e.g. number % 4 == 0 ?). Thus you'd have to use a pattern that gets all possible string combinations.

Try that one: `\b[048]\b|\b[13579][26]\b|\b[2468][048]\b|\b1[02][048]\b|\b11[26]\b`

- `\b[048]\b` matches 0, 4 and 8
- `\b[13579][26]\b` matches 12, 16, 32, 26 etc.
- `\b[2468][048]\b` matches 20, 24, 28, 40, 44, 48 etc.
- `\b1[02][048]\b` matches 100, 104, 108, 120, 124, 128
- `\b11[26]\b` matches 112 and 116

Note the `\b` which defines the whole word (in your case the prefix/suffix) must match the pattern. Without it, 136 might match `[13579][26]`, for example.

Edit: to allow leading zeros change the pattern to: `\b0{0,2}[048]\b|\b0?[13579][26]\b|\b0?[2468][048]\b|\b1[02][048]\b|\b11[26]\b` (note that `0{0,2}` could also be written as `0?0?`).

Edit 2: you might get rid of the `\b` if you split the ip address and only have a string containing the prefix/suffix. If you then call `matches(...)` you should be fine without the `\b`.

Pattern for `matches(...)` calls (no `\b`, allows leading zeros): 
`0{0,2}[048]|0?[13579][26]|0?[2468][048]|1[02][048]|11[26]`

Comment: No, 136 won't match `[13579][26]`.

Comment: @aioobe That depends on how it is called. 136 wont match as a whole but the 36 part in it might match.

Comment: Right, as long as you stick to `String.maches` or `Matcher.matches` and avoid `Matcher.find` etc, you should be fine though. Alternativly you could replace all `\b` with `^...$` I suppose.

Comment: The edits and comments to this answer are exactly why you don't want to use regular expressions for this problem. It's hard to get right and hard to understand whether it's right or not.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using regex, you can also do:

```
int prefix = Integer.parseInt(ipAddress.split(".")[0]);
if ( (prefix <= 128) && (prefix % 4 == 0)) {
    //success
}
else {
    //failure
}
```

Comment: this is much better than some incomprehensible regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate the IP address subnet prefix number, you can build a regex by brute force by including the multiples of 4 up to 128: `/0|4|8|12|16|20|24|28|32|...|120|124|128/`

You can simplify this slightly by noting that if multiples of 4 end in the two digits even+{0,4,8} or odd+{2,6}.

Other than this brute force method, there is no way to implement what you want cleanly and compactly - regexes work on individual characters, not on the semantic interpretation of the number (so no comparisons, no arithmetic).

Comment: This is soooo much better than a solution that tries to make a fancy pattern (ie: Thomas's solution). It may be long, but it will execute fast and it's instantly obvious what matches.

Comment: I effectively did mention Thomas' solution when I talked about "end[ing] in the two digits", heh.